# Why is out of bounds error thrown?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following code that goes through an `ArrayList` of size 8.

```
public Tile[] getTiles(){

    Tile[] tiles = {};

    for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){

        try {
            tiles[i] = board.get(i);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            System.out.println(i + " is out of bounds");
        }

    }

    return tiles;
}
```

However it outputs

```
 0 is out of bounds
 1 is out of bounds
 2 is out of bounds
 3 is out of bounds
 4 is out of bounds
 5 is out of bounds
 6 is out of bounds
 7 is out of bounds
 8 is out of bounds
```

Why are all elements in the `ArrayList` out of bounds?

Answer (score 1):

`tiles` is initialized to be an empty array (0 length). That's your problem.
It makes `tiles[i]` out of bounds for any `i`.

You should initialize `tiles` this way, to give it the same length as the size of the `board`:

```
Tile[] tiles = new Tile[board.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to empty array.

`Tile[] tiles = {};`

and you are trying to access empty array with an index value e.g. 1,2..... etc. That's why its showing outofbound.